# VLC tv card streaming

Tags: linux, streaming, vlc-media-player, video-streaming

I'm trying to stream the output of my desktop's tv card to my laptop using vlc without success. I have on both pcs ArchLinux installed.

I'm stuck here:

```
$ cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:norm=pal-nc:frequency=543250:size=640x480:channel=0:input-slave=alsa:///dev/dsp:audio=0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=3000,ab=256,vt=800000,keyint=80,deinterlace}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=192.168.0.2:8080}' --ttl 12
VLC media player 1.1.4 The Luggage (revision exported)
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_ADDRESS")
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_BUS_TYPE")
[0x1c9e480] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

[0x1c9e480] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x1ca1500] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x1bb3120] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x1c9f940] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x1ca4850] main access out: creating httpd
[0x1ebb340] mux_ogg mux: Open
```

And on my laptop:

```
$ vlc http://192.168.0.2:8080
VLC media player 1.1.4.1 The Luggage (revision exported)
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_ADDRESS")
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_BUS_TYPE")
Blocked: call to setlocale(6, "")
Blocked: call to sigaction(17, 0xb25c7058, 0xb25c70e4)
Warning: call to signal(13, 0x1)
Warning: call to signal(13, 0x1)
Blocked: call to setenv("ORBIT_SOCKETDIR", "/tmp/orbit-zf", 1)
Warning: call to srand(1287690122)
Warning: call to rand()
Blocked: call to setlocale(6, "")

(process:17933): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Warning: call to signal(13, 0x1)
Blocked: call to setlocale(6, "")
[0x8af5f04] main stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

mux=ogg is for vcodec=theora, maybe mux=ts?

Do you have any other software listening on port 8080? is 192.168.0.2 the address of the machine you're using for cvlc streaming?

Comment: I don't have anything on the port 8080. When a I get home I'll check with the mux thingy.

Comment: Nope, still the same with mux=ts.